# The meaning of the lambda and mu characters in calculations of vectors.

Tags: trigonometry, classical-mechanics

I am attempting to help my daughter with her homework for Mechanics at the first year of A Level (AS) The question asks:

Given that vector **a** = 2**i** + 5**j** and vector **b** = 3**i** - **j**, find
a) (lambda symbol) if **a** + lambda **b** is parallel to vector **i**

b) (mu symbol) if mu **a** + **b** is parallel to vector **j**

I have the solution to the problem from the CD supplied with the text book but I don't understand what the lambda symbol represents or the mu symbol. I have read the textbook and don't find any reference to what it means. Any explanations would be gratefully received. Thanks in advance.

Comment: From what I can infer from the statement, $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are two unknown (real values) you are asked to find. "Find $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, the real value such that $\vec{a} + \lambda\vec{b}$ and $i$ are parallel."

Answer (score 1):

Here $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are used as variables that stand for scale factors, in this case real numbers. That is, part a) asks what multiple of $\mathbf b$ needs to be added to $\mathbf a$ to make the resulting vector "parallel" to $\mathbf i$. (The answer to this part is $\lambda=5$, since $(2\mathbf i+5\mathbf j) + 5(3\mathbf i-\mathbf j)=17\mathbf i$.) Here "parallel" is not well expressed in the problem statement, since vectors are not lines that can be parallel; what they most likely mean is that the result is a multiple of $\mathbf i$.

Comment: "Parallel" is probably just used is for "colinear," which is well-defined (or, equivalently, "the lines whose direction is given by these two vectors are parallel.")

Comment: @ClementC.: There aren't "the" lines given by vectors; there are many lines in any given direction. Lines with direction vectors that are multiples of each other may be parallel, or they may be identical. Thus even this construction can't really make sense of the terminology. I think they simply misused "parallel to" to mean "a multiple of". I also don't remember seeing "collinear" applied to vectors; it's a geometric property of sets of points, just like being parallel is a geometric property of sets of lines.

Comment: I know what the relation between lines and vectors are :) (for the use of "collinear": mostly an artifact from my French: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colin%C3%A9arit%C3%A9 )

Comment: @ClementC.: I wasn't writing just for your benefit; I expected that you probably know better and were just writing somewhat inexactly; I was mainly writing for the benefit of everyone else, especially the OP, who seems not to be overly familiar with these things.

Comment: I figured (also, I did learn the slight difference between the use of collinear in the two languages, so thanks).

Comment: @ClementC.: The distinction may not be as strict as I thought in actual usage. Wikipedia and MathWorld both define "collinear" as a property of points, but searching for "collinear vectors" turns up lots of web pages, including e.g. [this math.SE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635838), where several users followed the OP's example of referring to collinear vectors.

Comment: I think I understand. By multiplying b  ( in a+b)  by the lambda value of 5,  the sum of the components on the j axis = 0 and the vector consists only of 17i . Would I be right then, saying that the mu value in mu a + b is -1.5?

Comment: @Alan: Yes, that's right.